# Basic Inheritance in C++ problems

Tags: c++, inheritance

I keep getting the error "expected class-name before ‘{’ token {"

I have tried multiple different approaches that I have found and none have worked. If anyone could help me I would be very appreciative.
my LinkedList.h file

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINLEDLIST_H


#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class LinkedList: public Node
{

private:
  Node<T>* head;
  Node<T>* current;
  Node<T>* tail;

public:
  LinkedList(){
  }

  virtual ~LinkedList(){
  }
};

#endif
```

and my Node.h file

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Node{

  private:
    T data;
    Node<T>* pNext;

  public:
    Node(){
      pNext = NULL;
    }

    ~Node(){
      delete this->pNext;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: `LinkedList` inheriting from `Node` does not make sense in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Node` is a template, not a type. `Node<T>` is a type. Use

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList: public Node<T>
{
  ...
};
```

**PS**

As a design choice, it does not make sense to inherit `LinkedList<T>` from `Node<T>`. You should be able to implement `LinkedList<T>` with just:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
   private:
      Node<T>* head;
      Node<T>* current;
      Node<T>* tail;
};
```

Comment: Note in particular the PS.

Comment: @DavidLattimerII, are you authorized to bestow sainthood? :) :) You are welcome.